# How to use this before super?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I know that `this` is not allowed before `super` but I need to do it. I was wondering if there was a legal way to do this in es6?

My code:

```
class DOMElement {
  constructor(aNodeName) {
    this.name = aNodeName;
    this.create();
  }
  create() {
    let domref = document.createElement(this.name);
    document.body.appendChild(domref);
    return domref;
  }
}

class Button extends DOMElement {
  constructor(aLabel) {
    this.label = aLabel;
    super('button');
  }
  create() {
    let domref = super.create();
    domref.textContent = this.label;
  }
}
```

If I don't set `this.label` before calling `super('button')` in `Button.prototype.create` then `domref.textContent` is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'legal' way.

It can be be a getter in cases where static property value is supposed to be used by parent class on construction:

```
get label() {
  return 'label';
}
```

In this case this means that class design is just wrong. There's nothing in parent class that would impose such restriction. Actually, `label` is only used by child class. It should be:

```
  constructor(aLabel) {
    super('button');
    this._domref.textContent = alabel;
  }
  create() {
    // if parent class is user-defined, it should be done there
    // instead of returning a value, because it doesn't make sense
    // to leave an important part of the object without a reference
    this._domref = super.create();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful info. Especially reason for class design being wrong. I have changed it so it is like your example (rather then the getter, as I wasnt able to tell the getter the value of `aLabel` from the constructor of `Button` before `DOMElement.create` ran). Is this possible though? Telling the getter the value of `aLabel` from the constructor?